# Find limit of sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help to find the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} $$

I've tried this:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{n^2+n+1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}}$$

but what's next?

Comment: You forgot to write $\lim$ twice and $x$ should be replaced by $n$

Comment: @amsmath sure, thx!

Comment: Since the square root is continuous over the positive reals, you can bring the limit inside the square root: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac 1 n + \tfrac{1}{n^2}}} = \sqrt{\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac 1 n + \tfrac{1}{n^2}}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's nice, now observe that

- $\frac1n \to 0$
- $\frac1{n^2} \to 0$

therefore

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\to \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+0+0}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
$n^2
\lt n^2+n+1
\lt (n+1)^2
=n^2+2n+1
$,
$n
\lt \sqrt{n^2+n+1}
\lt n+1
$
so
$1
\gt \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}
\gt \dfrac{n}{n+1}
= 1-\dfrac1{n+1}
$.

Therefore
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}
=1
$.